# Cannot open include file 'thread' in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2012, cocos2d-x

I am trying to compile a Cocos2D cpp-test project and i am facing the following errors (lots of them):
"error C1083: Cannot open include file 'thread': No such file or directory".
I've read many questions here at Stackoverflow about this issue, but unfortunately, nothing that could help me. Anyone knows what can i do to solve this?

Comment: I don't think this question should be marked as a duplicate. The linked answer expressly only solves the problem by telling the user to upgrade to Visual Studio 2012. In the tags, however, the user indicated that they're already using VS2012. The linked answer isn't going to be much help to them.

Comment: Are the errors related to your code or Cocos? Can you show us the top section where you include the headers?

Comment: This header is used by The cocos2d libraries, i dos not code anything, all i dos was just open de cpp-test and ask to build it.

Comment: The C++11 header ``<thread>`` is not present in VS 2010, but is present in VS 2012 or later. If you create a simple test app that has ``#include <thread>`` it should build, Try that first to make sure this isn't some corrupted setup issue. Also make sure your project is building with _Platform Toolset_ ``v110`` and not ``v100``.